# I am looking for Danish/Dutch/English/Finnish/French/German/Italian/Norwegian/Spanish/Swedish/Turkish sms corpora

Tags: computational-linguistics, datasets

for my dissertation I am looking for sms corpora. I am mainly interested in automatic sms notifications that are sent to users when they buy things online or pay using credit cards (confirmation messages).

I would be interested in the following countries:
Danish
Dutch
English
Finnish
French
German
Italian
Norwegian
Spanish
Swedish
Turkish

Can you tell me if there are any sms corpora available for sale or free of charge that would fit these requirements? Or do you know if there are any such sms notifications sent to users in countries that speak the languages I mentioned above?

Comment: Countries don't speak languages.

Comment: I think Open Data SE is a better fit for this question.

Comment: Thanks A. M. Bittlingmayer! It would be great if they had English version of their www or am I blind?

Comment: You should probably try to ask the corpora list.